# How to scp files with certain name to another server?

Tags: linux, scp

I have some files in a directory called `info` where I need to copy over files containing keyword `food` to another server. So the files can be `food#give.json`, `food#take.json` etc.

```
scp -i "t2microkey.pem" -r ~/info/['food' pattern files] ec2-user@example.sky.com:/home/ec2-user/some_dir/
```

I found out this question in stackoverflow. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138007/copying-files-with-particular-names-to-another-folder but I am not sure how do I use this solution in my case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below command to transfer the file, I just used it and it is working fine for me.

```
scp -i ~/<path-to-key>/<key-pair-name>.pem -r ~/info/food#* ec2-user@3.80.81.43:~
food#give.json                        100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00    
food#take.json                        100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

Directory Structure :

```
<some-directory-name>
        |-- food#give.json
        |-- food#take.json
```